# Replaced md-dialog with modal ui bootstrap,trying to find the locals attribute duplica

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i had to replace my md-dialog with an angular model UI bootstrap. in the md-dialog, i used the `locals` attribute to send `anguler.copy`, from the main controller into the dialog controller.
my question is, how do i get the same result with modal UI bootstrap?

md-dialog code (the old version)

```
$scope.notefullScreen=function(event){


                        $mdDialog.show({
                        controller: DialogNoteFullscreenController,
                        templateUrl: 'views/schedule/note-fullscreen.html',
                        targetEvent:event,

                        locals: {
                        editNote: angular.copy($scope.noteEdit), 
                        editPtivacy:angular.copy($scope.privacyOptions),
                        detailsFull:$scope.details

                        }        

                    }).then(function () {

                        }, function () {

                        });
```

modal ui code: ( in progress new version, what i have so far)

```
 $scope.notefullScreenNew = function (event) {

                            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                                templateUrl: 'views/schedule/schedule-extended-note-popup.html',
                                controller: ScheduleService.NotePopupCtrl,
                                targetEvent: event,
                                resolve: {
                                editNote: function () { return angular.copy($scope.noteEdit); },
                                editPtivacy: function() { return angular.copy($scope.privacyOptions); },
                                detailsFull: function(){return $scope.details;}
//                                locals: {
//                                    editNote: angular.copy($scope.noteEdit),
//                                    editPtivacy: angular.copy($scope.privacyOptions),
//                                    detailsFull: $scope.details
                                    // attachmentFull:angular.copy($scope.attachment)

                                }


                            });


                            modalInstance.result.then(function () {

                            }, function () {

                            });
                        };
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure it as something to do with the resolve attribute

Comment: It does indeed. Assembling an answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular-ui-bootstrap can resolve locals for the modal controller through the `resolve` attribute. These will then be available to your modal controller function as function parameters.

To adapt this to your scenario, it would become:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/schedule/schedule-extended-note-popup.html',
                controller: ScheduleService.NotePopupCtrl,
                targetEvent: event,

                resolve: {
                            editNote: function()( {
                                return angular.copy($scope.noteEdit);
                            },
                            editPtivacy: function() {
                                return angular.copy($scope.privacyOptions)
                            },
                            detailsFull: function() {
                                return $scope.details;
                            }
                         }
                    });
```

These will then be passed into your `NotePopupCtrl` as function parameters with the same name (just like the injections);

Sidenotes: I assume your attribute `editPtivacy` was supposed to be `editPrivacy`, also I don't think angular-ui-bootstrap supports the `targetEvent` attribute.